# What is the best to check a form input just for a name and not an extension

Tags: php, regex, arrays

In my form there is an input to re-name the file.  When they choose a file to upload it is checked to make sure it is only a .pdf file. I am trying to check the input to make sure they did not add a file extension to the new name. I am trying to check for any variation of 'pdf' Here is what I have but is there a better way to do this. Any help welcome, Thanks

```
  <?php
    function get_file_extension($pdf)
    {
     return substr(strrchr($pdf,'.'),0);
    }

    $pdf = "test.pdf";

    $test = strstr($pdf, '.');
    $pdf_ext = array('.pdf','.PDF','.Pdf','.PDf','.pdF','.pDf','.PdF','.PdF');
    $test =  get_file_extension($pdf);
    if($test == in_array($test,$pdf_ext)) {
       echo 'you do not a .pdf';
    } else {
       echo 'name ok';
    }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `strtolower` or `strtoupper`:

```
if(strtolower($test) == 'pdf') {
   echo 'pdf';
} else {
   echo 'no pdf';
}
```

Or

```
if(strtoupper($test) == 'PDF') {
   echo 'pdf';
} else {
   echo 'no pdf';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of not allowing the user to enter a name with a file extension of .pdf, you can check if they did, and remove it for them.

```
<?php

function get_filename_without_pdf($file){
    preg_match('/(.+?)(\.pdf)?$/i', $file, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}

echo get_filename_without_pdf('test1.pdf') . PHP_EOL;
echo get_filename_without_pdf('test2.PdF') . PHP_EOL;
echo get_filename_without_pdf('test3.txt') . PHP_EOL;
echo get_filename_without_pdf('test4') . PHP_EOL;
```

**output**

```
test1
test2
test3.txt
test4
```